# Worklight WL.JSONStore Replace Doc failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have initialize a collection. In that i have a single doc which holds UserPreferences. I an trying to updated few fields of this doc. But fails with errorCallback.

```
var dataToUpdate = {
                                userPreferencesID:1,
                                firstname:'Test Name',
                                lastName: 'Test Name 2'};   
WL.JSONStore.get(tableName).replace(dataToUpdate).then(successCallback).fail(errorCallback);
```

If some forum i could see the syntax

`WL.JSONStore.get(tableName).replace(query, option).then(successCallback).fail(errorCallback);`

Which one is correct. I tried both, but failed to update the record.

IBM Worklight Version 6.1.0.2

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` API takes a JSONStore document as the first parameter. For example:

```
{_id: 1, json: {userPreferencesID: 1, firstname: 'Test Name', lastName: 'Test Name 2'}}
```

Notice the `_id` and `json` keys. You're not passing a document as the first parameter.

Here's the [API documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/JSONStoreInstance.html%23replace) for the replace API in Worklight v6.1.

You get JSONStore documents when you use, for example, the `findAll` API:

```
WL.JSONStore.get('collection').findAll()
.then(function (jsonstoreDocuments) {
  // [{_id: 1, json: {name: 'carlitos', age: 99}}]
});
```

The example above presumes the JSONStore collection is not empty, if it's empty you'll get an empty array back (i.e. `[]`).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I got it. I completely forgot the _id part. Good Catch.